# Lists: prevent LaTex from splitting items

Tags: equations, amsmath, lists, page-breaking, itemize

Problem:

I've got a list in LaTeX (`\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` but some items are spread over multiple pages. In general this makes sense since LaTeX is able to split in the items so that there is not that much whit space on one page.

However, in my case, this is not desired. I have a list in which I want to enumerate equations (normal equation numbering doesn't help in this case) and every item of that list should have some kind of a heading line. Now the equations of one item should not be separated from its heading (this looks really ugly).

Until now I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item <Heading>
        \vspace{1ex}
        \begin{align*}
            mathText
        \end{align*}
    \item <Heading>
        \vspace{1ex}
        \begin{align*}
            mathText
        \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Problem with that is that I cannot simply put the whole `align*` blocks into a `fbox{}` or a `\begin{minipage} ... \end{minipage}`, since then LaTeX gives me the error, that it cannot use align* inside a fbox or minipage

Does anyone know how to prevent LaTeX from splitting up these single Items? (or maybe another workaround for equations)?

Best wishes and thanks in advance

Comment: Putting `align*` inside a `minipage` doesn't throw any errors for me; have you tested it with your MWE?

Comment: I'm so sorry somehow I failed in such an easy task. Actually I don't know what I was doing wrong back then.  Would you post this as an answer, so that I can accept it? ;)